# How to cast instance of Enumerable<T>.Where(Predicate) to IEnumerable<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-4.0, ienumerable

I'm writting a c# code generator. In some place I must cast return type of Linq's method like WhereSelectListIterator to IEnumerable type. How can I do it?

Scenario:
I have an instance of a List named aList. I write following expression in a Textbox:

```
aList.Where(item => item.StartsWith("s")).Select(item => item.ToUpper()).ToList().Count
```

I need to write an application to evaluate my expression. I know that i must write an C# code generator to evaluate my expression.
If I evaluate above expression directly it is works. But suppose that I have following scenario :

```
public Interface IInterface
{
}
public class MyClass:IInterface
{
    public int Id = 10;
    public IInterface GetInstance()
    {
        return new MyClass();
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var myClass = new MyClass();
        myClass.GetInstance().Id.ToString();
    }
}
```

When I use Id property after calling GetInstance() method it cause to CLR raise an exception because IInterface hasn't Id property. I need to cast return type of GetInstance() to MyClass first then use Id property.
How can I do this cast dynamically.
One solution is using dynamic object.

```
var myClass = new MyClass();
dynamic x = myClass.GetInstance();
dynamic y = myClass.Id;
y.ToString();
```

But dynamic object has problem with Extension methods(ex : Where(), Take() , ...). What can I do?

Comment: btw, `Where(predicate).Count()` should be replaced with just `Count(predicate)`

Comment: I know about Count(), but i want to aList.Where(predicate).Count that Count is belong to a List<T> evaluated without error. What casting I apply in this case?

Comment: dynamic object is useful when calling method is non extension. but in extension method what I must to do in this case?

Comment: Based on your comment on the answer below, it sounds like you're trying, for `List<String>`, to determine that the type of `T` is `String` - is that correct?

Comment: Yeah. In reality I want to get T dynamically and then do casting dynamically too.

Comment: Why GetInstance() returns the interface and not the class? Could you change the Id field to a property and add it to the interface as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to the question you ask in the title, The result of `Enumerable<T>.Where(Predicate)` implements `IEnumerable<T>`, just cast it, no need to do anything fancy. See here: [Enumerable..Where(TSource) Method (IEnumerable(TSource), Func(TSource, Boolean))](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx)

As for the rest, why are you trying to generate C# code? If you're trying to evaluate a code snippet that was entered at runtime, why not use the C# compiler to compile it? I Googled for "C# programmatic compilation", and the first result was this Microsoft support page: [How to programmatically compile code using C# compiler](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304655)

Comment: I think you don't understand my request. For resolving problem I must split my expression by dot first, because as I mentioned in above scenario. So when I have IEnumerator<T>.Where(predicate) how can I understand T exact type(string or int or ...). 
in myClass.GetInstance().Id.ToString(); how can i guess proper type for casting ---> (myClass.GetInstance() as MyClass).Id;
My problem is finding MyClass type for doing proper casting dynamically.

Comment: But he's right about the return of Where() is a Queryable<T> which happen to implement IEnumerable<T> as well. No need to cast.

Comment: David is correct. The type parameter: T is inferred by the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

You can call extension methods on `dynamic` objects like this:

```
dynamic result = Enumerable.Where(collection, (Func<dynamic, bool>)delegate(dynamic item)
                                              {
                                                   return item.Id == id;
                                               });
```